# Função Jquery não encontra a Controller quando subo para o servidor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Durante o desenvolvimento a função abaixo encontra a Controle e faz a requisição corretamente, porém após publicação no servidor a função não encontra mais a Controller:

Durante o **desenvolvimento** tenho que deixar assim:

```
url: "/Controller/Action",
```

Quando subo para o **servidor** tenho que alterar e deixar assim:

```
url: "/MeuSite/Controller/Action",
```

```
function carregaComboEmpresa() {
    $.ajax({    
        //url: "/MeuSite/Controller/Action",       
        url: "/Controller/Action",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        data: null,
        success: function (data) {          
        },
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É uma péssima ideia usar isso desta maneira.

Já existem soluções prontas pra isso, use [`Url.Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
function carregaComboEmpresa() {
    $.ajax({       
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        data: null,
        success: function (data) {          
        },
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Ok @LINK funcionou obrigado, porém uma pequena correção a sintaxe é essa '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")'

Comment: Verdade, @Front Obrigado por avisar.

Answer (score 2):

Acontece porque você esta chamando sua url com um caminho absoluto (pois ele começa com `/`).
existem 2 formas simples de evitar isso:

faça seu ambiente de desenvolvimento ter a mesma estrutura do seu ambiente de produção, no caso, se você estiver usando um `MAMP` ou similar, basta colocar todo os seu projeto dentro de um diretorio chamado `MeuSite` e apontar o servidor para o diretorio que contem `MeuSite`.

outra forma é usar uma url relativa, que dependeria do local onde seu arquivo `.js se encontra`, por exemplo

```
../Controller/Action
```

Que indica que a Url deve descer 1 nível e entrar no diretorio Controller. isso funcionará seu o seu `.js` estiver em

```
MeuSite/js/script.js
```

por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Isso ocorre porque os caminhos até a aplicação no servidor e no seu ambiente de depuração (*debug*) são diferentes, como você mesmo deixou claro na pergunta.

Quando você for fazer uma requisição ao seu *controller* via Javascript, você precisa obter o endereço correto. A minha sugestão é a seguinte, em duas partes:

- Em cada página do sistema, você coloca um input com o caminho correto da aplicação. Para não replicar código, você pode colocar isso uma única vez no seu `_layout.cshtml`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="caminho" value="@Url.Content("~/")" />
```

Esse `@Url.Content("~/")`, quando interpretado pelo Razor, retorna o caminho até a raiz da sua aplicação, completo. Vale a pena testar e conferir.

- Na hora de chamar o controller via Javascript, sua URL fica assim:

```
var url = $("#caminho").val() + "controller/action"; // o caminho já inclui um "/".
```

Aí você pode usar a variável `url` como o caminho para uma requisição ajax, ou seja:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post"
    // etc., etc.
})
```

Fazendo dessa forma, você não precisa misturar código Razor com código Javascript.